# SwitchPreference onChecked/onClick Listener

Tags: java, android

I've been racking my brains all night but can't seem to accomplish this one small thing. I would like to add a SwitchPreference into my PreferenceActivity of an app. Below is a picture.

Before I say too much, my problem is exactly this: I cannot seem to put a listener on just the Switch part of the preference. I am able to set an onPreferenceTreeClick and an onPreferenceClick on the preference, and that works fine if I press on the text portion. But When the Switch itself does nothing when I change it from OFF to ON.

I've read the documentation on [SwitchPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/SwitchPreference.html). I also looked at the android/packages/Settings and it looks like AOSP uses a Switch and not a SwitchPreference for Wi-Fi and Bluetooth.

Here is my attempt (working if you press on the entire preference item, but not if you just press the Switch):

Sample:

```
public class Preferences extends SherlockPreferenceActivity {

public static final String PREF_THEME = "pref_theme_interface";
public static final String PREF_ROOT = "pref_root";
public static final String PREF_APP = "pref_app";

public static SharedPreferences mTheme;
private static SharedPreferences mUpdate;
public static SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor;

public boolean SDK_COMPAT = true;

boolean pSwitch = false; 
boolean update = true;

Preference autoUpdate;

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            this.finish();
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(MainActivity.THEME);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_preferences);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        SDK_COMPAT = false;
    }

    mUpdate = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    update = mUpdate.getBoolean("update", false);

    // Load the preferences from an XML resource
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

    setPreferenceScreen(createPreferenceSDK());

}

private PreferenceScreen createPreferenceSDK() {
    // Root
    PreferenceScreen root = (PreferenceScreen)findPreference(PREF_ROOT);

    PreferenceCategory prefApp = (PreferenceCategory)findPreference(PREF_APP);

    //root.addPreference(prefApp);

    if (SDK_COMPAT == true) {
        pSwitch = true;
        autoUpdate = new SwitchPreference(this);
        autoUpdate.setKey("auto_update_pref");
        autoUpdate.setTitle(R.string.auto_update);
        //autoUpdate.setSummary(update == false ? "Disabled" : "Enabled");
        prefApp.addPreference(autoUpdate);
    } else {
        pSwitch = false;
        autoUpdate = new CheckBoxPreference(this);
        autoUpdate.setKey("auto_update_pref");
        autoUpdate.setTitle(R.string.auto_update);
        autoUpdate.setSummary(R.string.auto_update_summary);
        prefApp.addPreference(autoUpdate);
    }

    autoUpdate.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
            mEditor = mUpdate.edit();
            boolean checked = ((SwitchPreference) preference)
                    .isChecked();
            if (checked) {
                update = true;
                mEditor.putBoolean("update", true);
                mEditor.commit();
                autoUpdate.setSummary(update == false ? "Disabled" : "Enabled");
            } else {
                update = false;
                mEditor.putBoolean("update", false);
                mEditor.commit();
                autoUpdate.setSummary(update == false ? "Disabled" : "Enabled");
            }
            return true;
        }

    });

    return root;
}
```

So to reiterate my question in case I lost you. How does one set a listener on the Switch portion of the SwitchPreference? Please be kind if it is something so obvious. It was pretty late last night when I tried to add this.

Thank you so much in advance.

Notes:
1. I am not opposed to sticking with the CheckBoxPreference, but I prefer to use Switch because it looks nice.

1. Yes I know there is an easier/better? way of adding dynamic preference using res/xml and res/xml-v14 instead of doing the SDK check. I just did that for testing.

[picture of preference screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1KWq.jpg)

**EDIT**

Hopefully this helps someone else! Thanks Tushar for suggestion :-)

```
autoUpdate.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference,
                Object newValue) {
            boolean switched = ((SwitchPreference) preference)
                    .isChecked();
            update = !switched;
            mEditor = mUpdate.edit();
            mEditor.putBoolean("update", update);
            mEditor.commit();
            autoUpdate.setSummary(update == false ? "Disabled" : "Enabled");

            return true;
        }

    });
```

Comment: Have you tried using setOnPreferenceChangeListener instead?

Comment: Tushar, actually I haven't tried that. Let me give it a go. Thank you.

Comment: tell me how it goes. I'm curious.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This is what I did and it seems to be working ok. Funny thing with the isChecked() though. It is returning the opposite of what I expect... I edited the original question with method

Comment: Yeah, toggle buttons are very undesirable in UI in my opinion because they're hard to judge from a quick glance (ex: does "on" text mean it's on, or does it mean I can turn it on?). I'll submit my solution as an answer so others can find it easier.

Comment: Yeah I agree with you on the toggle state visibility on user-end. I set a summary that makes it easy to see though. Thanks again for the suggestion :-) Not sure why I didn't try that to begin with

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use `setOnPreferenceChangeListener()` instead of `setOnPreferenceClickListener()`.

Answer (score 8):

Working code

```
public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_notification);

            SwitchPreference vibrateSwitch = (SwitchPreference) findPreference("notification_vibrate");

            if (vibrateSwitch != null) {
                vibrateSwitch.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference arg0, Object isVibrateOnObject) {
                        boolean isVibrateOn = (Boolean) isVibrateOnObject;
                        if (isVibrateOn) {
                            Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                            v.vibrate(400);
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still haven't figured out a good way for doing this I have figured something out that doesn't create multiple calls to `onPreferenceChange` which clicking the preference does. I wrote it in another question: [dual functionality SwitchPreference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17588533/1570640).